How do I search pages in a specific hierarchy in Confluence efficiently?
I'm trying to integrate Confluence into a local C# application.
The goal is to find specific pages within a space using the API.
These pages follow a hierarchy, which is roughly planned but not fixed:
CustomerPage = Each customer has a dedicated page with brief information.
  |
  -> ArticlePage = Each customer can have many articles. Contains general article info.
    |
    -> ProcessPage = Each article always has the same processes. There's a ProcessPage for each process (e.g., Purchase, Sale, Packaging).
    ...
  ...
...

I want to build this hierarchy using the API (already implemented) and then find the correct pages in a smart way.
For example: "I want the ProcessPage for Purchase for customer x and article y" or "I want the ArticlePage for article y of customer x" or even "I want all ProcessPages for article y of customer x".
I've tried three approaches:

Using the hierarchy (with parents and children) and page names: Too many API calls, hierarchy can be changed by users, and I don't want to plan for all edge cases.

Using Labels: Fewer API calls, but labels can also be added/changed by users. Many edge cases (e.g., deleted pages retain labels). Labels can't be explicitly added or removed without being associated with a page.

Using Content Properties and CQL: Way less API calls. This seems like the best approach. It offers key-value pairs for flexible searching. However, using CQL seems to require writing a custom app, possibly hosted somewhere like Atlassian Forge:
https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/how-may-i-search-a-content-property-via-rest-cql-search/8368
https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/how-to-define-index-schema-for-content-properties-through-rest-api/54750


Is diving deeper into option 3 a good idea, or is there a better approach?
Ideally, I'd like custom key-value pairs on each page that I can search with CQL.
